# Android Development Studio

Tags: java, android

Hi all as i have faced a problem during my Java coding in android development studio, as stated it always give me the org.apache.http.NameValuePair i deprecated error and i am not sure how to solve it, the same goes for BasicNameValuePair.
[image]

however i have already imported both the NameValuePair and BasicNameValuePair and it still doesn't work.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Deprecated is a warning, not an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecated is just a warning, so you can compile regular. However, take a look Android website http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html

You must use `openConnection()` instead. See more detail in this tutorial: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html